# Line spacing between lines containing inline math

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fractions, mathtools, inline

Honestly I give up on this. I searched for a solution to this for so long, but nothing seemed to work (well) for me.

I just want my equations to no longer look squashed together, referring to how small the spacing is between two lines, but also to how small fractions look by default, for example (hence also the desperate `\displaystyle\frac` declaration).

Too lazy to make an example snippet. Here's a MWE made with a text snippet right out of my actual doc.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Replace multiplication symbol
\let\oldtimes\times
\let\times\cdot

% Use the second \epsilon variant
\let\oldepsilon\epsilon
\let\epsilon\varepsilon

% Display fractions nicely
\let\oldfrac\frac
\renewcommand{\frac}{\displaystyle\oldfrac}

\begin{document}
 \subsubsection{Determinarea condiției de funcționare cinematice a mecanismului}
 $V_{Tg_1} = V_{Tg_2}$. Se cunoaște că
 $V_{Tg} = \omega \times R_d$, rezultă
 $\omega_1 \times R_{d_1} = \omega_2 \times R_{d_2}$, unde \\
 $R_{d_1} = \frac{m \times z_1}{2} =$ raza de divizare.
 $\omega_1 \times \frac{m \times z_1}{2} = \omega_2 \times \frac{m \times z_2}{2}$ rezultă \\
 $\frac{m \times z_1}{2} = \frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} \times \frac{m \times z_2}{2}
 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$.

 \subsubsection{Determinarea expresiei raportului de transmitere al mecanismului}
 $\frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$ rezultă că
 $i_{\text{angrenaj\_cilindric}} = \frac{\omega_3}{\omega_1} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$
\end{document}
```

You can see my problem.

[image]

Equations are basically going one into another.

If I use the package `setspace` and wrap the math into a `spacing` environment, I get closer to what I want, but it still is ugly.

```latex
[...]

 \begin{spacing}{1.8}
  $V_{Tg_1} = V_{Tg_2}$. Se cunoaște că
  $V_{Tg} = \omega \times R_d$, rezultă
  $\omega_1 \times R_{d_1} = \omega_2 \times R_{d_2}$, unde \\
  $R_{d_1} = \frac{m \times z_1}{2} =$ raza de divizare.
  $\omega_1 \times \frac{m \times z_1}{2} = \omega_2 \times \frac{m \times z_2}{2}$ rezultă \\
  $\frac{m \times z_1}{2} = \frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} \times \frac{m \times z_2}{2}
  \Leftrightarrow \frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$.
 \end{spacing}

 \subsubsection{Determinarea expresiei raportului de transmitere al mecanismului}
 \begin{spacing}{1.8}
  $\frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$ rezultă că
  $i_{\text{angrenaj\_cilindric}} = \frac{\omega_3}{\omega_1} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$
 \end{spacing}

[...]
```

[image]

1. There's a lot of spacing between the math and the sections (especially at the end of an equation and the beginning of a section). This can be fixed by using `\vspace`-s with negative values, but I'm asking if there's a better way to do it
2. It seems like the spacing between the lines is not done between the bottom edge of the previous line and the top edge of the current line (as can be seen where there are fractions), but between the text on the same line as the equations (I can kind of live with this, at least things aren't mashed together anymore).

What can I do?

Comment: inline math is designed to fit within standard paragraph line spacing, but you are forcing over-sized math with `\displaystyle`  your definition makes the entire expression  displaystyle not just the fraction as you do not apply any group to scope the declaration, there is no way tex can preserve baselines if you do this, you need to increase the baseline or use display math.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle already in Plain TeX with Knuth Font, the height plus depth of `$f_i^j$`  is about `12.22pt` but the baselineskip is `12pt`, thus creating very ragged spacing. The `$f_j^i$` has the exact same height plus depth, but of course a larger depth.

Comment: @Andy3153 `\def\baselinestretch{1.3}\selectfont` will increase line spacing for your paragraph.  You can then do `\def\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont` afterwards.  There may be some better LaTeX idiom (I don't know well LaTeX, and `\baselinestretch`, `\selectfont` are LaTeX commands, I don't know best way to use the former in particular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of writing of math terms is not adopted to usual way of their in line writing for. See if the following rewriting is acceptable to you.

BTW, in math terms  `\cdot` is not needed to say that wo variables are multiplicated. This is self-understanding without it.

[image]

***Edit:**
Added co0mments to preamble code (considered @David Carlisle comment, thank you David)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Replace multiplication symbol %%%% why you use this multiplication symbols?
                                %%%% btw, \cdot and times not necessary meaning the same
%\let\oldtimes\times
%\let\times\cdot

% Use the second \epsilon variant %%%% this is not good decision. Don't doing this
%\let\oldepsilon\epsilon
%\let\epsilon\varepsilon

% Display fractions nicely  %%%% don't doing this, it is source of your bad typography
%\let\oldfrac\frac
%\renewcommand{\frac}{\displaystyle\oldfrac}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Determinarea condiției de funcționare cinematice a mecanismului}
$V_{Tg_1} = V_{Tg_2}$. Se cunoaște că $V_{Tg} = \omega  R_d$, rezultă $\omega_1 R_{d_1} = \omega_2 R_{d_2}$, unde 
$R_{d_1} = m  z_1/2=$ raza de divizare. 
\[
\omega_1 \frac{m  z_1}{2} = \omega_2 \frac{m z_2}{2}\ .
\]
\subsubsection{Determinarea expresiei raportului de transmitere al mecanismului}
 $\omega_2/\omega_1 = z_1/z_2$ rezultă că $i_{\text{angrenaj\_cilindric}} = \omega_3/\omega_1 = z_1/z_2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't leave `\renewcommand{\frac}{\displaystyle\oldfrac}` in the answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i overlooked this ... I would remove it ASAP. Thank you for notified me about thi

Comment: It's recommended to not leave a blank line in the input before a display -- it allows a page break, and also leaves more space than usually desired in the output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right, Now corrected. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm 100% sure this is the right way to go about doing things, but I am just going to follow @user691586 's solution in a comment on my main post

Comment: @Andy3153, I wonder, why you not upvote and even accept the answer when you 100% sure, that sis right way to go. Since you prefer another (wrong)  way, it is now unclear what you actually after. So I suggest to close your question as  *Needs details or clarity*. Sorry ...

Comment: I forgot to accept the answer, my bad